# how to lock record in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a reservation system for stuff that you could rent.
I would like to restrict multiple users from reserving the same item.

I display a list, which user can click on the item to check the details.
If any user has already opened the detail view then other user can not open it at the same time.
I am maintaining a flag call `is_lock` to check if the record is already locked but I was facing issue when multiple users clicked on the same item at the same time.

So I implementing pessimistic lock, which reduced the rate of occurrence of this issue but multiple users opening the same item but it did not completely fixed the issue. I am still facing the same thing.

```
begin
Item.transaction do
  item = Item.lock.where(id: item_id, is_lock: false)
  item.is_lock = true;
  item.save!
end
rescue Exception => e
  # Something went wrong.
end
```

Above is the code that I have implemented.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

***EDIT:***

I've tried the solution provided by @rmlockerd in following way:

1. Run rails in 2 separate consoles.
2. Fetch record with lock that has id:100 from console-1.
3. Fetch to fetch the same record from console-2.

But the above test failed as I was able to fetch the same record from both console even though the record was locked from console-1.

Run rails in 2 separate consoles.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you wrapping the above snippet in a transaction? A row lock will only work in the context of a transaction.

Comment: @rmlockerd Yes, the above snippet is in transaction, which is wrapped inside a begin-rescue.

Comment: @rmlockerd I will modify the snippet also.

Answer (score 0):

It might be misleading to just look at the snippet you provided, but there does seem like a possible race condition due to your `.where` predicate.

If User2 attempts to get a lock on the same item after User1 but before first the transaction commits, the `.where` will still return the original record with `is_lock` false. The default behaviour for `.lock` is to simply wait its turn for a lock. So User2 would block until the original transaction commits, then get a lock and proceed to set `is_lock` to true as well.

The good news is that when you get a lock, Rails reloads the record so you are getting the latest data. Checking `is_lock` after obtaining the lock should eliminate that race condition, like so:

```
Item.transaction do
  item = Item.lock.find_by(id: item_id, is_lock: false) # only 1, so where is unnecessary
  return if item.blank? || !item.is_lock

  item.update!(is_lock: true)
end

# I have the lock stuff...
```

The `.lock` method also takes an optional 'locking clause' -- which varies based on the database you use -- that can be used to configure the locking behaviour. For example, if you use Postgres, you could do:

```
Item.transaction do
  item = Item.lock('FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED').find_by(id: item_id, is_lock: false)
  return if item.blank?

  item.update!(is_lock: true)
end
```

The `SKIP LOCKED` clause directs Postgres to automatically skip any record that is already locked. In the race condition described above, the second call to `.lock` would bail immediately and return nil, so a simple check of item presence would suffice. Check out the [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) or [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) documentation if you're interested in database-specific locking clauses.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did try with find() but faced the same problem.
Is there any difference between where() , find() and find_by().

Comment: It has no effect on your problem. ``.where`` returns an array of all matching records and ``.find_by()`` returns just the first. Since in your case ``id`` is one of the attributes, there will only ever be one match so ``.where()`` is unnecessary. ``.find()`` looks up by only record ID.

Comment: I tried with find_by() also but there is no effect, plus 'UPDATE SKIP LOCKED' is throwing error in rails console. How I tested this is : fetch the record by locking the record with particular ID from console 1 and again tried to fetch the same record with lock from console 2.
Console 2 should skip the locked record but it does not, it returns the same record that I locked from console 1.

Comment: My mistake, it would be ``FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`` -- I've edited the answer to fix. I've replicated the code above (using a nice long ``sleep()`` after the lock to ensure conflict) and it seems to do as you want. Can you edit your question with details of what is happening in the failing case?

Comment: I've added a edit in my questions and included the steps that I used to check.